# uwp sqlite add-migration crashes when updated to a new project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have SQLite database in my **uwp** project (with entity framework) as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).

I had a uwp project targetting **Anniversary update** so at that time this documentation was old and I had to add the database code and stuff within my uwp project (and not in a .Net standard project) so that project got installed by a lot of user over the store and they all obviously now have a database created on their devices, let's say **Db1.db**.

After a year I updated my app and retargeted it to creators update and I did this in a new project because I had to make some major changes to my app so I wanted a clean project to start with, I added my features and also added the database stuff the same way as previous project with same database name **Db1.db** and then I published it to store as well.

**Problem**

Now when I published my second package it crashed on **DBContext.Migrate()** method which is supposed to be in constructor of **app.xaml.cs** I understand it crashed because the name of the database was same and both projects had only 1 migration known as **MyFirstMigration** and somehow that conflicted and crashed the application. I can confirm it because soon after I made an update to my 2nd package (which targets creators update) and changed the database name to **Db2.db** and now I didn't get a crash because now the app is ignoring the old database on user's device and just creating and using the new database, which is not the best way because my existing user's can't access the data they had in **Db1** although the new users won't be affected as they have all their data only in **Db2**.

Here is the situation right now:

**User Group 1** these users have their old data in **db1** and new data in **db2**

**User Group 2** these users have all of their data in **db2**

I probably will keep making new projects from scratch to target newer SDKs, because I like to make newer major updates from scratch which helps me refactoring whole app easily. So how can I use the same database name in my newer projects without crashing the app ? I am not changing my model, my model will remain the same and I want to keep using only 1 database file no matter how many new projects I publish to the store, the app should always talk to that 1 database file. would this be possible if I just copied the **Migrations folder from my older project and paste it new project and keep that migrations folder consistent across my newer versions? or is there any other way?**

Also note that now in my newer projects my min target will be fall creators update so I will use a .net standard library to keep my db stuff there as mentioned in the docs I mentioned above, so I would like to keep using **db2.db** in my new projects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems an issue about user data synchronization. As what I understand, you can use the **db2.db** in your new fall creators update UWP app(We will call it New Version), but after user upgrade your app to New Version and launch your app at the first time, you can check whether there exist a **db1.db** in your project, if it existed, you can copy the data from the **db1.db** to the new **db2.db**.

This way looks like to backup and restore, but in uwp app, update will not delete your **db1.db**, you just need to "restore" or copy the data to your new **db2.db** which is created by using the new feature of using EF Core UWP app, then you can just operate the **db2.db** to store the user data later and you no longer need to use the **db1.db** again.

**---Update---**

> are you saing everytime I create a new project I should copy data from previous database? means I cannot use same database file?

Actually, you just need copy once from db1.db to db2.db, because you have transformed your project to using EF Core. In the later version, since you have used the  EF Core, if you create a new project update, you can use the db2.db directly without any issue in my test.

> how can I check if old db exists?

As you have known the db file name and the file location, you can check whether the old db exist by checking whether the db file exist.

```
private async Task<bool> IsFileExisted(string fileName)
{
    var result= await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
    if (result == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) you provide, it seems the `Migrate` method is call in the App's Constructor, this will cause to use an async method toughly. So you can put the code of `Migrate` in App's `OnLaunched` event handler.

```
 protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
     using (var db = new BloggingContext())
     {
         //db.Database.EnsureCreated();
         bool isExist = await IsFileExisted("db1.db");
         if (!isExist)
         {
             db.Database.Migrate();
         }

     }

     Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

     // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
     // just ensure that the window is active
     if (rootFrame == null)
     {
         // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
         rootFrame = new Frame();

         rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

         if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
         {
             //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
         }

         // Place the frame in the current Window
         Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
     }

     ...
}
```

If you use this scenario, you will not need to create the db2.db, you can just use the db1.db in your New Version project.

> right now my latest project uses db2 so can I connect to db1 from this project without calling migrate function? (because migrate function crashes the app.) and then just copy data from db1 to db2.

The migrate function applies any pending migrations for the context to the database and will create the database if it does not already exist. You need to use the migrate function to create the database if it doesn't exist. Of course, if the db1.db exists, you can connect to db1 to get the data without calling the migrate function.

To implement it, you can follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) to create a `NewBloggingContext` class to inherit `DbContext` in the Model Library to connect to db1.db and copy the data.

Comment: the problem lies with migrate option, as I mentioned in my question if I create the new project in a new project in visual studio and upload that package, when the user updates the app and open it, the app crashes, because the database name conflicts, are you saing everytime I create a new project I should copy data from previous database? means I cannot use same database file? right now my latest update is using db2 , so if I create a new project update I need to copy data from db2 to new db3? doesnt seem to effecient, also how can I check if old db exists? bcz on migrate function it crashes.

Comment: right now my latest project uses db2 so can I connect to db1 from this project without calling migrate function? (because migrate function crashes the app.) and then just copy data from db1 to db2.

Comment: @touseef I have updated my answer, you can check it, please be free to tell me if you have any question about it.

Comment: @BreezeLio how did I transform the project to EFCore? in both versions of my project I am actually using the same method of creating and using the database, even the nuget packages version were the same between both projects, but now when I create the new version it will probably use efcore as I will be using a .net standard library, but between db1 and db2, I think whatever EF version I am using is the same

Comment: in the code above u r checking db1 exists and then if it doesnt u r doing a migration ( creation of db ) on which db? db1 or db2? which connection does dbcontext represent in ur example?

Comment: My above code is for only using db1 without creating db2, we can use db1 directly in your new version. If you have had db2 connection DbContext 
 now and also want to connect db1, you maybe also need to create a new DbContext child class to connect db1 and check whether db1 exist.